# ASP.NET Core - Storing encryption key to Redis

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, encryption, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm not very experienced with data protection mechanism, especially in .net core/Redis so I can't understand from the official doc what and how encryption key is taken to be stored in Redis:

```
var conn = $"{host}:{port}";
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(conn);

services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = conn;
        });
//here            
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToRedis(Redis, "DataProtection-Keys"); //where is the VALUE for the KEY? Should it be saved to Redis manually before call this?
```

So I'm wondering what kind of key I can use(I don't have any, how to create one?), where to store it and how to specify in the configs where to take it from.

When I run the app the record with key "DataProtection-Keys" added to Redis, but I don't know what the value is and if it's working at all.

So another question is - how to verify if the encryption works?

Please help me understand the basics, any examples are very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data protection system would help create and manage keys, and you need not to create/save it to Redis manually by yourself.

Besides, the `"DataProtection-Keys"` here in `.PersistKeysToRedis(Redis, "DataProtection-Keys")` method is a **RedisKey** that is the unique name of a piece of data, and the key that encryption requires would be stored as value (RedisValue).

> how to verify if the encryption works?

You can refer to the following code snippet to inject the `IDataProtectionProvider` and use it to create an instance of an `IDataProtector`, then encrypt and decrypt data.

```
IDataProtector _protector;

public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    _protector = provider.CreateProtector(" WebDataProtection.Controllers.HomeController.v1");
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var input = "hello world";

    // protect the payload
    string protectedPayload = _protector.Protect(input);
    ViewBag.ProtectedPayload = $"Protect returned: {protectedPayload}";

    // unprotect the payload
    string unprotectedPayload = _protector.Unprotect(protectedPayload);
    ViewBag.UnprotectedPayload = $"Unprotect returned: {unprotectedPayload}";

    return View();
}
```

Test Result

[image]